# Posting photos on a facebook page album using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, photo

Here's what I've done:

1. Get page access token from /me/account
2. Paste in on the graph explorer tool.
3. Make a post request with parameters named message, url (trying to upload via url) to [http://graph.facebook.com/{albumid}/photos](http://graph.facebook.com/%7Balbumid%7D/photos).
4. Graph returned a Id.

Comment: Please double check the album id in the url.

Comment: album id is ok. I figured we have to approve the photos after posting them with api. Any work around? I want it fully automated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem. We need to approve the photos from by going to the album as the Page.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. I went to album as my page. But there is no approval link

Comment: Can we automate that manual approval process? I know there app that simply upload photos to the album: without manual approval process