# uploading photos to facebook page album using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is a duplicate of the question "[Posting photos on a facebook page album using graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006283/posting-photos-on-a-facebook-page-album-using-graph-api)", but its unanswered.

What's happening is, I am uploading the photo to the page's album using the graph api and I am able to see the photo myself. But its not visible to anyone else.

The same thing works on another page, which I created myself.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Have you set the privacy the album to **"public"**? A link to the album would useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the app was in sandbox mode. I had to turn it off.