# Facebook photo album created by App - not visible to public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I just created a new page and a new app. I created an album and uploaded a photo to this new album using Graph API and Koala. I am able to view this new album and its photos in Facebook site. It shows public privacy only. But the album and its photos are not visible to others (both logged in users and guest users).

The albums/photos created manually via the Facebook site is visible to everyone.

I checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006283/posting-photos-on-a-facebook-page-album-using-graph-api/17008814#comment35527389_17008814) but could not find the approval link in the albums page while using the site as the Page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My application was in development mode. And hence photos created by it were not available to public. To fix this:

Goto App settings -> Status and Review and mark 'Yes' for the question `Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?`

Comment: A little update: This answer is still valid today (July 2017), but now you have to go to your app and go to "App Review" and you should see the option on top: "Make <your app name> public?". Set it to Yes and you are good to go.